# Find checkin comment info in TFS2010 Warehouse

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

Does anybody knows if the TFS 2010 Warehouse database (the one supposed to be used for reporting) keeps any information about the checkin comments for a changeset?

I can see the information via the TFS Explorer, like this

[image: image of tfs comments]

But if I try to extract the same information from the Warehouse database, also selecting every data from the changeset and code churn tables, I'm not able to find it (I've also tried to open every single database table!)

```
select * from FactWorkItemChangeset fwics
join DimChangeset dcs on fwics.ChangesetSK=dcs.ChangesetSK
where dcs.ChangesetID = 145640
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Massimo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *ChangeSet Title* field in Tfs_Warehouse.dbo.DimChangeset has the comment, albeit concatenated with the change set number.  Your query does return the field.

Answer (score 0):

Sample query:

```
select 
fwics.WorkItemID as [Work Item Id]
,dwi.System_Title as [Title]    
,dwi.System_WorkItemType as [Type]
,dcs.ChangesetID as ChangeSet_ID
,dcs.ChangesetTitle as [Comment]
,df.FileName as [FileName]
,df.FilePath as [Path]
,dd.DateTime as [CheckinDate]
,dp.Name as [Person]
from
DimChangeset dcs
join FactWorkItemChangeset fwics on dcs.ChangesetSK=fwics.ChangesetSK
join FactCodeChurn fcc on fwics.ChangesetSK=fcc.ChangesetSK
join DimFile df on fcc.FilenameSK=df.FileSK
join CurrentWorkItemView dwi on dwi.System_Id=fwics.WorkItemID
join DimDate dd on dd.DateSK=fcc.DateSK
join DimPerson dp on dp.PersonSK=dcs.CheckedInBySK
and fcc.TeamProjectSK = 80
order by [CheckinDate] desc
```